# Custom desktop icon with Inno Setup

Tags: icons, inno-setup

I have the following in my Inno Setup file which creates a desktop icon no problem:

```
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; \
    GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"
```

However, the main file that launches the program is a VBS file rather than an EXE. I'd like to have a nice icon on the shortcut rather than the VBScript one, but can't find an option to change the icon.

Is there such an option available to set a custom icon?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Inno Setup help about the `[Icons]` section says:

> **IconFilename**
>
> The filename of a custom icon (located on the user's
> system) to be displayed. This can be an executable image (.exe, .dll)
> containing icons or a .ico file. If this parameter is not specified or
> is blank, Windows will use the file's default icon. This parameter can
> include constants.
>
> > Example:
> > `IconFilename**: "{app}\myicon.ico"`

([source](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection))

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for that - I was expecting the icon to be set within the tasks section thus was looking in the wrong place in the help!

Answer (score 3):

You pasted the [Task] entry whereas the [Icons] entry is what creates the actual icon.
For that, you want to install a custom icon file, and set the IconFilename (and optionally IconIndex) parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Before you use Inno setup, change the .exe icon with windows platform. After you change it then use Inno, and your .exe file becomes the icon that you have changed before using Inno.

In other words: Inno setup uses default icon to launch as a .exe icon, so you can change the icon before use Inno. It works for me.

Comment: "change the .exe icon with windows platform" Unclear and apparently impossible without third-party software. https://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Icon-for-an-Exe-File https://www.howtogeek.com/75983/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-modify-the-icon-of-an-.exe-file/

Comment: Why should you change the icon for all VBS files on a user's system just to get the one you want for your own script? I'd uninstall any software that behaved that irresponsibly on my computer, and then go to every review site I could find to give extremely negative reviews of that app.