# Creation of Windows executable file (*.exe) with PyDev-Eclipse and CDT-Eclipse --- How?

Tags: windows, eclipse, pydev, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to create Windows executable files for Python and C/C++ code within the Eclipse workbench? If yes, then how can this be done?

Comment: See if [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) can help you.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I create .exe files from eclipse, in windows. Is not within the eclipse workbench but it might help you. To avoid problems, I would recommend to download everything for 32 bit even if you use 64 bit computer.

Install [python 2.6](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6/)

Install [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1)

Install [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)

In eclipse go to Help > Install new software and install pydev plugin from http://pydev.org/updates/

In windows preferences point the python interpreter to the location of your python.exe in your computer (C:/Python26)

you might need to add py2exe to the libraries

create a python module called setup.py with a code similar to this one:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=['H:/yourworkspace/YourPythonProject/src/yourprogram.py'])
```

open windows console and type
python H:/yourworkspace/YourPythonProject/src/setup.py py2exe

this will create a .exe located in C:/Python26/dist folder. It should work if you double click it but you cannot take it to a computer without python or any of the libraries that you´ve used. To do that, you can use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php).

It's very easy to use, basically it will ask for the location of the .exe, the dlls and folders that you want to add (I don't know about this so I add most of the things inside my C:/Python26/dist and it works). Inno setup will create an script and generate a .exe that you can install in any computer. You might need to [edit the [Icons] part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485355/custom-desktop-icon-with-inno-setup) of the script, I had problems with that before to add an icon to the application.

That should hopefully work,

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you're asking as you're mixing Python/C++ in your question...

If you want to embed Python in some library, Google for 'embed python in c++'

If you just want to package Python to run Python code with extension modules, search for py2exe or cx-Freeze (personally, I like cx-Freeze better).

I don't think any of this is PyDev/Eclipse dependent (this should be IDE agnostic).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Fabio's answer:

In terms of C/C++, if you compile it on windows, eclipse does create yourprog.exe file automaticaly in order to be executed (in case if you have your main function written in C/C++). Look for your executable in bin folder of your project.

In terms of compiler: I use Cygwin. It simulates Linux environment. It contains (not by default though) g++ compiler, which, because of cygwin, compiles it in binary that can be launched in Windows (i.e. .exe file). I am not sure exactly about whether Linux binary is then converted to Windows binary or it is directly compiled for windows, but I know that this .exe file alone works if you run it.

Let me know if you need help installing Cygwin.

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP is looking for a way to do this _within the Eclipse workbench_.

Comment: Additionally, _do your research_ is a poor answer.

Comment: Fixed. Will not be coming back here, if you feel something else is wrong - please, feel free to fix it yourself.