# Convert py to exe

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, cx-freeze

I have a program working with Tkinter. This is using Python 3. I want convert this py to exe. I found PyInstaller and Cx_Freeze. I tried to convert with cx_freeze (my setup.py file for cx_freeze is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25255169/)). The exe file is working on my Windows 10 PC, but it gives a compatibility error on Windows 7 PC.

Then, I converted with PyInstaller. This exe is working on my Windows 10 PC like cx_freeze's exe file. I never tried on Windows 7 PC, but I don't want to get an error again. How can I be sure about it will work on the Windows 7 PC?

Note: Windows 7 PC is my customer's so I don't want disturbing him too much.

I want convert py to exe for Windows 7, on Windows 10.

Comment: Look into [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) - specifically the "one file" mode. You have to test your application on platforms you wish to support. Period.

Comment: Thanks bro, I converted with PyInstaller's one file mod and sent to my customer. I hope it will work.

Comment: this thread could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187568/creation-of-windows-executable-file-exe-with-pydev-eclipse-and-cdt-eclipse

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running an x64 bit system, an x64 version of python and what version does your customer use?

The problem I believe you have is that you are trying to run an x64 application on an x32 computer, this is not possible since x64 is not supported. So you must make it an x32 application [This post might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006477/cx-freeze-and-python-3-4/45394342#45394342)